# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (60) caused by external access

Tags: mysql

I am trying to mySQL external access to macOS(PC B) from win10(PC A). 
First Run mysql server on two pc, created accounts in pc 'A', write grant query, and allowed access to all IPs.
I checked bind-address sentence in [my.cnf, my.ini] (set 0.0.0.0) and insert 'port=3306' too.

On PC A, could connect with

```
mysql -u root -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 3306
```

but, PC B couldn't connect with same sentence.
(To prevent confusion, all accounts have been named root.)

And, There was no problem when I entered

```
netstat -ant | grep 3306 

netstat -an | findstr 3306 (in win10)
```

to confirm.

But when I tried to access, generated an error like

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.30.1.23' (60)
```

**please give me idea to solve this error**

Comment: I've tried many ways out of the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Angry IP Scanner](https://angryip.org/download/#windows) and check if your host MYSQL port is open or not,
if not :

- check your destination path using TRACERT
- check destination/host firewall port access
- if you are using Docker don't forget to add port map into Dockerfile